# CSS animation from width 0 to 100

Tags: css, css-animations

Here is what I want to do: I want to play an animation on a div which starts from width: 0 to width: 100vw, then back to 0 BUT when it goes back to width 0, and I want to animate from the left to right, like a "continous" animation, not a "reverse". Like in the middle of the animation you can see the div, but when it goes back to width 0, it should disappear from left to right ( like the way it started ). I don't know how to explain this better...

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 1s in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes in-out {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    /* but starting to "disappear" from left to right, just like the way it appears */
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

change `left:0` to `right:0` in the middle of the animation:

```css
div.box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 1s in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes in-out {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100vw;
    left:0;
    right:auto;
  }
  50.1% {
    left:auto;
    right:0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    left:auto;
    right:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can also simplify using only `left`/`right`:

```css
div.box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 1s in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes in-out {
  0% {
    left:0;
    right:100%;
  }
  50% {
    left:0;
    right:0;
  }
  100% {
    left:100%;
    right:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can also do this without changing the width in case you only want the visual effect:

```css
div.box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 1s in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes in-out {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
  45%,55% { /*to stay a while full width*/
    transform:translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Another idea using `scale()`:

```css
div.box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 1s in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes in-out {
  0% {
    transform:scaleX(0);
    transform-origin:left;
  }
  45% {
    transform:scaleX(1);
    transform-origin:left;
  }
  55% { 
    transform:scaleX(1);
    transform-origin:right;
  }
  100% {
    transform:scaleX(0);
    transform-origin:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Also with `rotation()`

```css
div.box {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 1s in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes in-out {
  0% {
    transform:rotateY(-90deg);
    transform-origin:left;
  }
  45% {
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    transform-origin:left;
  }
  55% { 
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    transform-origin:right;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotateY(-90deg);
    transform-origin:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```